# Changing the drawing instruments on a fly

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have adjusted [openlayers basic draw example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=draw) and whenever I am **switching** from *Point* to *LineString* or *Polygon* drawing mode, it is working properly only for the **first time**, yet **fails for switching overtimes**.

***F.I.*** I cannot get back to drawing *Point* after using *LineString* (it continues to draw me LineString, yet log prints that drawingtool is *Point*)

My html for buttons in modal:

```
 <div class="modal-body row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <a id="Point" href="#" class="draw btn btn-primary btn-block"><span class="icon ion-android-pin"></span>  Point</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <a id="LineString" href="#" class="draw btn btn-primary btn-block"><span class="icon ion-android-pin"></span>  Polyline</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <a id="Polygon" href="#" class="draw btn btn-primary btn-block"><span class="ion ion-ios-grid-view-outline"></span>  Polygon</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><span class="ion ion-pinpoint"></span>  Coordinates</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is part  of js:

```
function addInteraction() {
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: features,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (drawtool)
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
}
$('.draw').on("click", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault(); - commented by me - no difference
  drawtool = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#drawModal").modal('toggle');
  addInteraction();
});
```

You can also find whole code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaharo/zuarah4t/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that everytime you are calling addInteraction() you are adding a new instance of ol.interaction.Draw to the map, so the existing one is never removed.

The quick and dirty solution is to remove the existing interaction before creating the new one.

Just add

```
map.removeInteraction(draw);
```

before

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw(...
```

See the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zuarah4t/3/

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't figure out how to remove existing interaction. Can you also give direction for cleaner and more thoughtful direction?